# Is it possible to add one more selector to flexslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am wondering, is it possible to add another selector to the Wootheme's flexslider? On different pages I am using different styles for my slides, thats why I would like to add to the `$.flexslider.defaults` something like:

```
selector1:".my_slides > li",
```

to the selector in flexslider, without removing default

```
selector:".slides > li".
```

I tried doing something like

```
selector:".slides > li", ".my_slides > li",
```

but it's not working.

Here is the the code where I use .slides and .my_slides (I don't know if there is difference, but I am using it inside Wordpress):

```
/* *********** (12) Display Post Format ******** */

function swm_display_post_format() {

    $format = get_post_format();

    if(empty($format)) {
        $format = 'standard';
    }
    if( $format == 'standard' || $format == 'gallery' || $format == 'image' || $format == 'video' ) {

        get_template_part( 'includes/' . $format );
    }
}



/* ************* (13) Blog Gallery Slider ************* */

if ( !function_exists( 'swm_blog_gallery' ) ) {
    function swm_blog_gallery($postid, $image_size) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                if ( $.browser.msie ){
                    if($.browser.version == '8.0') {
                         $("#flex-<?php echo $postid; ?>").flexslider({
                            slideshow: false,
                            controlNav: true,
                            smoothHeight: true,
                            start: function(slider) {
                                slider.container.click(function(event) {
                                    if( !slider.animating ) slider.flexAnimate( slider.getTarget('next') );
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }


               $("#flex-<?php echo $postid; ?>").imagesLoaded( function() {
                $("#flex-<?php echo $postid; ?>").flexslider({
                    slideshow: false,
                    controlNav: true,
                    smoothHeight: true,
                    start: function(slider) {
                        slider.container.click(function(event) {
                            if( !slider.animating ) slider.flexAnimate( slider.getTarget('next') );
                        });
                    }
                });
               });
            });
        </script>
        <?php

        $gal_images = rwmb_meta( 'swm_pf_gallery_photos', 'type=thickbox_image' );
        $meta_gallery_img_height = rwmb_meta( 'swm_meta_gallery_img_height');

        echo "<div class='pf_featured_img pf_l_img'><div class='swm_slider_box'><div id='flex-$postid' class='flexslider pfi_gallery'>";


        if ( $gal_images ) {
            echo "<ul class='slides'>";

            foreach ( $gal_images as $gal_image ) {
               //   $swm_gal_image = "{$gal_image['url']}";
                $swm_gal_image = swm_resize($gal_image['url'], 635, 425,  $meta_gallery_img_height, true,'c',true);
                    echo "<li><img src='$swm_gal_image' alt='' /></li>";
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        echo "</div></div></div>";
    }
}





/* **************** (12) Display MY Post Format **************************** */

function swm_display_my_post_format() {

    $format = 'gallery1';

    get_template_part( 'includes/' . $format );
}



/* ***********************(13) Blog MY Gallery Slider *********************** */

if ( !function_exists( 'swm_my_blog_gallery' ) ) {
    function swm_my_blog_gallery($postid, $image_size) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                if ( $.browser.msie ){
                    if($.browser.version == '8.0') {
                        $("#flex-<?php echo $postid; ?>").flexslider({
                            slideshow: true,
                            controlNav: true,
                            smoothHeight: true,
                            start: function(slider) {
                                slider.container.click(function(event) {
                                    if( !slider.animating ) slider.flexAnimate( slider.getTarget('next') );
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }


                $("#flex-<?php echo $postid; ?>").imagesLoaded( function() {
                    $("#flex-<?php echo $postid; ?>").flexslider({
                        slideshow: true,
                        controlNav: true,
                        smoothHeight: true,
                        start: function(slider) {
                            slider.container.click(function(event) {
                                if( !slider.animating ) slider.flexAnimate( slider.getTarget('next') );
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php

        $gal_images = rwmb_meta( 'swm_pf_gallery_photos', 'type=thickbox_image' );
        $meta_gallery_img_height = rwmb_meta( 'swm_meta_gallery_img_height');

        echo "<div class='pf_featured_img pf_l_img'><div class='my_swm_slider_box'><div id='flex-$postid' class='flexslider pfi_gallery'>";

        if ( $gal_images ) {
            echo "<ul class='my_slides'>";

            foreach ( $gal_images as $gal_image ) {
                //  $swm_gal_image = "{$gal_image['url']}";
                $swm_gal_image = swm_resize($gal_image['url'], 510, 410,  $meta_gallery_img_height, true,'c',true);
                echo "<li><img src='$swm_gal_image' alt='' /></li>";
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        echo "</div></div></div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
selector: ".slides > li, .my_slides > li"
```

This syntax:

```
$('selector1', 'selector2')
```

selects elements matching `selector1`, but only those that are descendants of elements matching `selector2`.

This syntax:

```
$('selector1, selector2')
```

selects both elements matching `selector1` and elements matching `selector2`. I assume the plugin would work the same way.

Comment: hi, Jason! I am sorry, I am new to javscript and jquery, could you please tell me a bit more how it should be done.

Comment: Try the part directly following "Try this". The rest is explanation.

Comment: yes, I tried it but only the .slides > li, is working, .my_slides > li - isn't.

Comment: If you reverse the order, does `.my_slides > li` work and not the other?

Comment: and there is one more part in the code where .slides > li is used. here is the code :

 if (typeof options === "object") {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    selector = (options.selector) ? options.selector : ".slides > li",
                $slides = $this.find(selector) ;

Comment: no, if I revers the order .my_slides > li, still isn't working.

Comment: Then I would guess there's something wrong with that selector. Update your question to include the `.my_slides` html

Comment: If it can help, here is the link to the whole slider code: 

https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is there. It would probably be helpful to post a new question asking why one selector works, but the other doesn't. It would probably be helpful to see the generated html in addition to the php code.